# Couldn't reference the figures

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I am trying to reference the figures in [2] with [1]. The figures are inside `multicols`. When I compile it, I just get `??` in the `ref`s. I get the error in [3]. What am I doing wrong?

[1] References to the figures

```
Fig.~\ref{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:A}
Fig.~\ref{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:B}
Fig.~\ref{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:C}
```

[2] Figures

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{multicols*}{3}
    \includegraphics[trim=0mm 0mm 17mm 0mm,width=.31\textwidth]{graphs/global-performance-A.pdf}\par\caption*{a) A}\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:A}
    \includegraphics[trim=0mm 0mm 17mm 0mm,width=.31\textwidth]{graphs/global-performance-B.pdf}\par\caption*{b) B}\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:B}
    \includegraphics[trim=0mm 0mm 17mm 0mm,width=.31\textwidth]{graphs/global-performance-C.pdf}\par\caption*{c) C}\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:C}
  \end{multicols*}
\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline}
\caption{Job makespan of A, B, and C executions (no faults).}
\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline}
\end{figure*}
```

[3] log file

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:makespan:performance:trendline:A' on page
7 undefined on input line 509.

Package caption Warning: \label without proper \caption on input line 524.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Package multicol Warning: multicols* inside a box does not make sense.
(multicol)                Going to balance anyway on input line 522.
```

Comment: Why twice `\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline}`??? Why this strange setup? And do you have compiled twice?. Isn't `subfig` package a better style?

Comment: I'snt using package `subcaption` more suitable to do the job? Uing `multicols` cannot be the solution you are trying to get.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because -- judging by a subsequent comment by the OP -- the problem was not related to anything shown in the posting.

Answer (score 1):

Arranging the three images inside separate columns does, per se, make it possible to cross-reference them. Instead, I would like to suggest you encase the images along with their associated `\caption` and `\label` instructions inside separate `subfigure` environments, within the overall `figure*` environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % Use a two-column layout
\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subcaption' environment
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t!]

\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[trim=0mm 0mm 17mm 0mm,width=\linewidth]{graphs/global-performance-A.pdf}
\caption{A}
\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:A}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill} % maximize whitespace between subfigures
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[trim=0mm 0mm 17mm 0mm,width=\linewidth]{graphs/global-performance-B.pdf}
\caption{B}
\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:B}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill} % maximize whitespace between subfigures
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[trim=0mm 0mm 17mm 0mm,width=\linewidth]{graphs/global-performance-C.pdf}
\caption{C}\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:C}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Job makespan of A, B, and C executions (no faults).}
\label{fig:makespan:performance:trendline}
\end{figure*}

Fig.~\ref{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:A},
Fig.~\ref{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:B},
Fig.~\ref{fig:makespan:performance:trendline:C}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've found the error. I had to comment this:

% \counterwithin{paragraph}{subsection}
% \hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

Comment: @xeon123 - It would have been really useful if you had featured this code in your original example.